# Use Tidesdk to query mysql (external/localy)

Tags: php, mysql, tidesdk

i've looked into the tidesdk and found no way to query a local or external mysql database.

is there a way to connect to mysql and query a database/table, maybe via php?

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no native way of accessing MySQL through TideSDK. You are welcome to help us create the native module for TideSDK to access MySQL.